# размещение сайта(веб приложения)

Tags: java, веб-программирование, сервер, веб-сервер, хостинг

есть созданный сайт(веб приложение) на java созданный как Dynamic Web Project запуск в Apache Tomcat прошел успешно [image: запуск в Apache Tomcat прошел успешно]

после я перекинул папку с файлами на хостинг [image: папка с файлами]
результат меня не порадовал http://webtest1.ga/ , http://webtest1.ga/WebContent/ вопрос что не так ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю твой хостинг не поддерживает работу java приложений. Предположу, что это хостинг только для php.

И я ни когда не видел, что бы веб приложения на java разворачивали путём копирования исходников в корень сайта. Хотя такое можно настроить, но маловероятно).
Обычно приложение компилируют и упаковывают в war файл. Потом этот файл разворачивают на сервере приложений(tomcat, wildfly и д.р) через web консоль. Путём копирования тоже можно развернуть, но это зависит сервера приложений. К примеру у wildfly есть директория deployments которую он постоянно проверяет на наличие новых файлов.